# How to upload video through flask and display it in bootstrap table?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to make an analysis report page through Bootstrap. I've been doing data science stuff but kinda new to web development.

What I want to display on the bootstrap table is to show video first, and synchronize it with other tables with the timeline.

I've made other tables, but I have no freaking idea how to upload video file through python flask and display it on Bootstrap table. I've tried, but cannot display video in my Bootstrap table.

Here is my full HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Intelliwebi DashBoard</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="static/css/dashboard_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
        <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <!-- Navbar Brand-->
            <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="/">Intelliwebi</a>
            <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!-- Navbar Search-->
            <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Navbar-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Activity Log</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="layoutSidenav">
            <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="upload_video">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                                Upload Video
                            </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="visualization">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                                Analysis report
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                        <div class="small">Logged in as:</div>
                        {{ session['UserName']}}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <h1 class="mt-4">Analysis report</h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Analysis report</li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <script>
                                session['VoiceExpress']
                            </script>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is the result of your pitch deck. The result includes the analysis of your pitch length, voice emotion, your pitch script.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Add a new card to display the video -->
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-file-video me-1"></i>
                                Video
                            </div>
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Add a table header for the video cell -->
                                        <th>Video</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id='table-body'>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Add a table cell for the video player -->
                                        <td id="videoCell">
                                            <video controls id="videoPlayer">
                                                <!-- Display the uploaded video -->
                                                <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename) }}" type="video/mp4">
                                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                            </video>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-chart-area me-1"></i>
                                Voice emotion analysis
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myAreaChart" width="100%" height="30"></canvas></div>
                            <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Y axis: Strength of emotion, X axis: Timeline</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-pie me-1"></i>
                                        Pitch script length segmentation
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="chart-container">
                                            <canvas id="myPieChart" width="200%" height="75"></canvas>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Add a new card to display the speech data -->
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <i class="fas fa-file-alt me-1"></i>
                                    Script
                                </div>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id='table-body'></tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
                <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                            <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2023</div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                &middot;
                                <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="static/assets/demo/chart-area-demo.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="static/assets/demo/chart-pie-demo.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="static/assets/demo/speech.js" type="module"></script>
<!--         <script src="static/assets/demo/video.js" type="module"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And the HTML section about displaying the video is:

```
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <i class="fas fa-file-video me-1"></i>
                                    Video
                                </div>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <!-- Add a table header for the video cell -->
                                            <th>Video</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id='table-body'>
                                        <tr>
                                            <!-- Add a table cell for the video player -->
                                            <td id="videoCell">
                                                <video controls id="videoPlayer">
                                                    <!-- Display the uploaded video -->
                                                    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename) }}" type="video/mp4">
                                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                                </video>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated</div>
                            </div>
```

And python flask code(application.py):

```
from flask import Flask, current_app, request, redirect, session, jsonify, render_template, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_video(filename):
    #print('display_video filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('/static/uploads', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)

@app.route('/temp_vis_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def temp_vis_data():
    with open('/Users/jaeuk/Documents/GitHub/ServiceWeb/static/assets/demo/total_result.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return jsonify(data)
    pass

@app.route('/visualization', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def visualization_page():
    filename = request.args.get('filename', None)
    return render_template('charts.html', filename=filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Another python flask code(upload.py):

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, flash, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

@app.route('/uploads', methods=['POST'])
def upload_video():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No video selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    else:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        flash('Video successfully uploaded and displayed below')
        return redirect(url_for('upload.html', filename=filename))
```